# Getting all elements in a string message without space or \n C#

Tags: c#, string

Okay, so I wasn't sure how to call it and how to research it, but if the question has been asked before, please tell me and give me the link. If the title is too vague, please edit it as well.
So, I happened to need to change phone, but the old one has many playlists. The problem is, it isn't a simple text or XML file. Well, it certainly contains text, but it has an encryption or something. Well, in any case, since I don't have much knowledge in cryptography and stuff, I was thinking about reducing the results. I need to recover ALL path containing "my_music" (folder), which means to stop at the ".mp3". The problem is, well, how do I do that? And for all of them?

I'm guessing I'll store the path in a string array (string[]), but it really is more about the string manipulation. Do I have to use, say, the Length parameter? I don't see how I could get the next ".mp3" after the folder and cycle through all of them.

Here is one of the playlists (my Non-UTF8 settings are on Japanese BTW):

ｴ    = 8  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/philosophy of ours.mp3 ・    = 8  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/philosophy of yours.mp3     3 .  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/potted one.mp3     1 ,  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/reply.mp3 ﾚｵ    ) $  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/_.mp3    3 .  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/raised bed.mp3      3 .  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/remembrance.mp3    ? :  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/daisy orgel ver..mp3 [6ｴ    9 4  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/anemone flaccida.mp3
 1 ,  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/harvest.mp3     9 4  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/scattered flowers.mp3    - (  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/daisy.mp3                I      ・     ﾁ      ・     #      Z     ・     ﾔ
        F     ・

Comment: "Okay, so I wasn't sure how to call it and how to research it, but if the question has been asked before, please tell me and give me the link. If the title is too vague, please edit it as well. " -- er, no. That's all stuff **you** need to do. Put in *some* effort yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this using Regular Expressions?

```
string sample = @"ｴ = 8  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/philosophy of ours.mp3 ・ = 8  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/philosophy of yours.mp3 3 .  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/potted one.mp3 1 ,  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/reply.mp3 ﾚｵ ) $  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/_.mp3 3 .  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/raised bed.mp3 3 .  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/remembrance.mp3 ? :  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/daisy orgel ver..mp3 [6ｴ 9 4  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/anemone flaccida.mp3
1 ,  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/harvest.mp3 9 4  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/scattered flowers.mp3 - (  fs:/card0/my_music/rewrite/daisy.mp3 I ・ ﾁ ・ # Z ・ ﾔ
F ・";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(my_music.*?\.mp3)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (var match in rgx.Matches(sample))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", match);
}
```

Output:

```
my_music/rewrite/philosophy of ours.mp3
my_music/rewrite/philosophy of yours.mp3
my_music/rewrite/potted one.mp3
my_music/rewrite/reply.mp3
my_music/rewrite/_.mp3
my_music/rewrite/raised bed.mp3
my_music/rewrite/remembrance.mp3
my_music/rewrite/daisy orgel ver..mp3
my_music/rewrite/anemone flaccida.mp3
my_music/rewrite/harvest.mp3
my_music/rewrite/scattered flowers.mp3
my_music/rewrite/daisy.mp3
```

Comment: The "*?\" means basically "All until"? What does the "\" and the parentheses do? Sorry really. I have no experience using RegEx.

Comment: @GabrielFilion Here's a reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Learning regular expressions is probably worth your time and can be used (with slight tweaks) in lots of different programming languages, text editors, and some command line tools.  To answer your question.  The . without the \ means match to any character.  The * means zero-or-more of what came before, so .* means any string of characters, and the ? makes it non-greedy (so it matches as little as possible while still working). The \. just matches the period. Parens capture into a group.